# How to enable Ubuntu to read/play Arabic subtitles?

Tags: language-support, input-language, arabic

I can't watch any movie with Arabic subtitles, I have tried to open the sub file and it displayed as all Chinese characters.

How can I get Arabic subtitles working?

Comment: What program are you using to play movies? Is it Totem? VLC? Have you tried other players? I recommend editing your question to provide this information. (You can also take a look at the edit I made and, if you like, edit further as necessary in case it doesn't fully describe the problem.)

Comment: it's not relevant to Ubuntu, because the subtitle is read by the video player

Answer (score 5):

I advise you first to use VLC. To install vlc:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

When you open VLC go to *Tools → Preferences → Subtitles and OSD* and then choose *Arabic (windows-1256)* in the *default encoding*.

[image: Subtitles configuration dialogue]

Now you have just to put the `.srt` translation file in the same directory of the video  you want to watch